# How do I change the default OS to start with NOOBS Dual Boot headless?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, headless, noobs

I installed two operating systems on my raspberry pi using NOOBS.
In my configuration the pi works headless, that means I won't be able to chage the os to start at runtime since I have no monitor and keyboard attached.

How can I change the OS to which the pi boots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For doing so, login to your raspberry py with putty or another SSH client.

Now you have to change one value in the noobs.conf. To be able to access this config file you have to do some stepps:

#### Make directory to mount

```
mkdir /tmp/noobs
```

#### mount noobs partition

```
sudo mount  /dev/mmcblk0p3 tmp/noobs
```

#### look which os is on which partition

```
cat /tmp/noobs/installed_os.json
```

This part is interesting:

```
"name" : "RISC OS",
"partitions" : [
  "/dev/mmcblk0p5",
  "/dev/mmcblk0p6"
],
...
```

the mmcblk0p **5** is important

#### edit the noobs.conf with e.g. nano and change the value `default_partition_to_boot`to the partition number

```
sudo nano noobs.conf

[General]
default_partition_to_boot=5
display_mode=0
keyboard_layout=us
language=en
```

#### Now finally perform a reboot to chage to the other os

```
sudo reboot
```

If you want, you can make a shell script which changes the value and performs a reboot. That would make it easier, if you want to do this often.

Comment: hi, I can't find this noobs.conf anywhere. I did mount all the mmcblk0pX partitions and I am unable to find this file. My NOOB have 4 os installed.

Comment: @Ricardo new versions of NOOBS has these config files at mmcblk0p5.  See the [Noobs partitioning explanation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained)